# kableExtra: Cannot save HTML table with math expressions & can't get in-line hist to display with Latex table

Tags: html, r, math, latex, kableextra

I want to save a table in R as an image that both includes **math expressions** in the column names and an **in-line histogram** from the `spec_hist()` function in kableExtra. Ideally, I would like the table formatted as a Latex table, but HTML would do too.

The problem I have is that when I try to **save** a kable HTML table, the math expressions are not properly interpreted, but the in-line histogram shows up nicely.

Meanwhile, if I try to save a kable Latex table, the math expressions are interpreted correctly, but the histogram will not appear.

Could this be a bug (two bugs?) in kableExtra? Or am I missing something?

Note that the kable HTML table looks perfectly fine (math expressions and in-line plot) in R Studio/R Markdown. But I want to save an reuse the image.
The kable Latex table however never shows the in-line histogram, whether displaying in R or saved to a file.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df <- mtcars[1:6,] %>% 
          mutate(`$\\theta_{boot}$` = "") %>% # add an empty column where the in-line histograms will go
          rename(`$mpg$` = mpg, # rename some columns to math expressions
                 `$\\bar{cyl}$` = cyl, 
                 `$\\bar{disp}$` = disp,
                 `$hp$` = hp, 
                 `$drat$` = drat)

# create dummy data for the in-line histograms
hist_dat <- list(runif(20), runif(20), runif(20), runif(20), runif(20), runif(20))


# Make HTML Table
kbl(df, escape = FALSE, booktabs = T, format = "html") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Some Header" = 6, "Some Other Header" = 7)) %>% # add header
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 12) %>%
  column_spec(12, image = spec_hist(hist_dat)) %>% # add in-line hist
  pack_rows("Group 1", 1, 3) %>%
  pack_rows("Group 2", 4, 6) %>%
  kable_paper() %>%
  as_image(file = 'temp.png')
  #save_kable(file = 'temp.png')
```

The above saves this image:
[image]

The histogram is there, but the column names are printed as the literal rather than the interpreted math expressions.

Now for the Latex version:

```
# Make Latex Table
kbl(df, escape = FALSE, booktabs = T, format = "latex") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Some Header" = 6, "Some Other Header" = 7)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"), font_size = 12) %>%
  column_spec(12, image = spec_hist(hist_dat)) %>%  
  pack_rows("Group 1", 1, 3) %>%
  pack_rows("Group 2", 4, 6) %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = TRUE) %>%
  as_image(file = 'temp_latex.png')
  #save_kable(file = 'temp.png')
```

Using format = "latex" and full_width = TRUE generates the following file:
[image]

Now the column names are interpreted correctly, but the histograms are not plotted.

I also found no difference whether I used `as_image()` or `save_kable()` to save the images.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Hardware notes: I'm on a Mac with a LaTeX install. Graphics work fine, although all calls that involved latex failed on my Windows machine (same code, MikTeX, Ghostscript & Magick installed).

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2021                        
month          05                          
day            18                          
svn rev        80317                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
nickname       Camp Pontanezen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you knit the rmarkdown document then both the pdf document is generated (with the image included in the document) and the image is separately saved as a file.

It seems as if the column spec needs to be adjusted to take into account the row names.

Adding column widths helps to manage the table on the page.

````
```{r, results='asis'}

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)


kable(df,
      format = "latex",
      escape = FALSE,
      booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Some Header" = 6, "Some Other Header" = 7)) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 8, full_width = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "30mm") %>% 
  column_spec(2:12, width = "6mm") %>%
  column_spec(13, image = spec_hist(hist_dat, col = "red")) %>%  
  pack_rows("Group 1", 1, 3) %>%
  pack_rows("Group 2", 4, 6) %>%
  as_image(file = 'temp/as-image.png') 
  # as_image(file = 'temp/as-image.pdf') # works as pdf as well
```
````

[image: Image saved as pdf or png]

Comment: Thanks! Fixing the column specs and getting the output after knitting worked! 
However, one problem I have now is that I see "NA" to the immediate left of each of the histograms. (It doesn't happen with the mpg data but with my own data, even though I've made sure that the column is empty - defined like theta_boot above - and the data is a data.frame not a tibble.)

Comment: Have you tried setting the knitr option knitr.kable.na = '' ''? If this does not work I would suggest creating a minimal data frame which reproduces this behaviour and asking another question how to remove the "NA", referring to this question.